# Unable to find bower_components in the directory above

Tags: javascript, html, bower

I have the following directory structure in one of my projects:

```
/web
  /bower_components
    /bootstrap
    /jquery
    /typeahead.js
  /views
    /index.jade
```

I'm trying to use these components from my `index.jade` file in the following way:

```
link(src='../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
script(src='../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
script(src='../bower_components/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.min.js')
```

but it doesn't work (there's no `bootstrap`-related styles on this page and jQuery code doesn't work).

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Should I refer to these components in a different way?

Should I place `bower_components` directory in another folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the file path to be relative to where you are compiling the jade file to.

For example, if you render the jade like this:

```
/web
  /index.html
```

the source paths would be

```
link(src='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
script(src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
script(src='bower_components/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.min.js')
```

Comment: I render `index.jade` file from the `server.js` that is located in the root of the `web` directory

Comment: You are using node.js?

Comment: Yep (I_need_to_place_these_characters)

Comment: Have you tried this? `app.use(express.static('bower_components'));` and using absolute paths in your jade like this `script(src='/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')`? Are you getting 404 errors?

Comment: Yep, it works (altough I need to replace `src` for the `link` to the `href`). I wonder is it the appropriate way to do it?

Comment: link tags need href attributes, script tags use src.

Comment: Nah, I asked about whether it is the appropriate way to handle `bower_components` (I mean to call `app.use` method)